# Fastest way to create a dataframe from a dict of lists

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, performance

I have a case where I have my initial data-structure as:

```
import datetime
data = {
   'col1': [1,2,3,4],
   'col2': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
   'col3': [datetime.datetime.now() for _ in range(4)],
   'col4': [[1], [2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9,19]],
}
```

I want to create a pandas data frame out of this - So, I do:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

My biggest worry here is that I have multiple small dictionaries like the above coming in a streaming fashion. So, using `pd.DataFrame()` for each small dict - is very slow.

On my actual data, it seems to be taking nearly 30-40 ms per dict. I am trying to achieve <5ms ideally... I've been wondering if it is possible.

If I could accumulate all the data together - that would have made things faster cause accumulating it in a Python list and then creating a DF out of it is much faster. But I need it to be on the smaller dicts for my application.

**Approach 1**: I tried doing something like:

```
data = {
   'col1': np.array([1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0], dtype=float),
   'col2': np.array(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], dtype=object),
   'col3': np.array([datetime.datetime.now() for _ in range(4)]),
   'col4': np.array([[1], [2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9,19]]),
}
```

thinking that if I can give pandas numpy arrays directly - it would be much faster. But that did not help much ...

**Approach 2**: I also tried using the internal function `pd.DataFrame._from_arrays` in pandas and giving the right inputs for that:

```
df = pd.DataFrame._from_arrays(
    [data[k] for k in data.keys()],
    pd.Index(list(data.keys())),
    pd.RangeIndex(0, len(data[next(iter(data.keys()))])),
)
```

and that seems to make it 5-10% faster

I have been reading about pyarrow and whether that can help me in this case. But any experiment I run with arrow seems to be making things slower - not faster.
Any suggestions ?

Edit: Added a reproducible example

Some assumptions I can make:

1. All the lists will be the same length
2. The data type in the list will be only float or datetime or object (str, arrays, dict) ... I avoided int due to the None issue they have
3. There are no corrupt or wrong values (i.e. no mixing of data types)

Minimum reproducible example I am using (uses random data):

```
import datetime
import random
import string
import time
import pandas as pd

random.seed(42)
trials = {
    "num": {},  # 1 numeric column
    "num10": {},  # 10 numeric columns
    "text": {},  # 1 string column
    "text10": {},  # 10 string columns
    "date": {},  # 1 date column
    "date10": {},  # 10 date columns
    "mixed": {},  # 1 numeric, 1 string, 1 date column
}

def gen_num(size):
    return [random.random() for i in range(size)]

def gen_text(size, strlen=100):
    return [
        "".join(
            random.choice(string.ascii_letters)
            for j in range(random.randint(1, strlen))
        )
        for i in range(size)
    ]

def gen_date(size):
    return [datetime.datetime.now() for i in range(size)]

for size in [1, 10, 50, 100, 1000]:
    trials["num"][size] = {"num": gen_num(size)}
    trials["num10"][size] = {f"num{k}": gen_num(size) for k in range(1, 11)}
    trials["text"][size] = {"text": gen_text(size)}
    trials["text10"][size] = {f"text{k}": gen_text(size) for k in range(1, 11)}
    trials["date"][size] = {"date": gen_date(size)}
    trials["date10"][size] = {f"date{k}": gen_date(size) for k in range(1, 11)}
    trials["mixed"][size] = {
        "num": gen_num(size),
        "text": gen_text(size),
        "date": gen_date(size),
    }

def run_tests(func, funcname, input="dict"):
    times = {}
    for name in trials:
        times[name] = {}
        for size in trials[name]:
            start = time.perf_counter()

            for _ in range(100):
                out = func(trials[name][size])

            end = time.perf_counter()
            duration = (end - start) * 1000  # in ms
            times[name][size] = duration
            # print(f"{funcname} - {name} - {size} --- {duration:.3f} ms")
    tot_time = sum(v2 for v1 in times.values() for v2 in v1.values())
    tot_count = sum(1 for v1 in times.values() for v2 in v1.values())
    print(
        f"{funcname} - Total Time ".ljust(30, "-")
        + f" {tot_time:.3f} ms in {tot_count} iter"
    )

def f1(data):
    # Directly let pandas do its thing
    return pd.DataFrame(data)


def f2(data):
    # Use the internal function: pd.DataFrame._from_arrays 
    return pd.DataFrame._from_arrays(
        [data[k] for k in data.keys()],
        pd.Index(list(data.keys())),
        pd.RangeIndex(0, len(data[next(iter(data.keys()))])),
    )

run_tests(f1, "simple-pd")
# simple-pd - Total Time ------- 2152.598 ms in 35 iter
run_tests(f2, "fromarr")
# fromarr - Total Time --------- 2051.039 ms in 35 iter
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. Are all the list of all the data the same length (4, each time)? Are all the keys the same (col1, col2, col3, and col4 each time)?

Comment: +tag: performance?

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Added the MRE I am using for my local micro benchmarking. And added the performance tag.

Comment: I would go with multiprocessing if possible.  I've tested `polars` but its even a bit slower than pandas. *Maybe* some "cache + deepcopy + values assignment" strategy would work. Tested that deepcopy of dataframe is about 5x faster than creating it. Still needs to find it in cache and assign values though

Comment: If you are willing to work with pyarrow Table instead of pandas DataFrame, `pa.Table.from_pydict(data)` is much faster